# What did Bnei Ammon do?

Tags: rashi, ki-teitzei, moav-moab

In Parshat Ki Teitzei there's the mitzvah that Bnei Ammon cannot marry into the Jewish people. Same is true for Bnei Moav. The verse says it's because they didn't greet the Jews with bread and water.

Rashi ([23:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14085&st=&pgnum=274)) says that we learn from here that causing others to sin is worse than killing them, since you kill them in this world and in the next world. This is because Bnei Moav hired Bilaam and the Benot Midian to seduce the Jews.

However, I don't recall the Torah mentioning anything about Bnei Ammon causing the Jews to sin. What is Rashi (quoting Sifre) referring to?

Comment: I do not see in [Rashi in Parshas Ki Teitzei](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14085&st=&pgnum=272) "that we learn from here that causing others to sin is worse than killing them, since you kill them in this world and in the next world. This is because Bnei Moav hired Bilaam and the Benot Midian to secude the Jews."

Comment: You were two pages too early...http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14085&st=&pgnum=274 הא למדת שהמחטיא לאדם קשה לו מן ההורגו, שההורגו הורגו בעולם הזה, והמחטיאו מוציאו מן העולם הזה ומן העולם הבא, לפיכך אדום שקדמם בחרב לא נתעב וכן מצרים שטבעום, ואלו שהחטיאום נתעבו:

Comment: If you look at the original Sifre (which Rashi is quoting), "ואלו" is referring to Ammon and Moav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the classic *Meforshei Rashi* and none of them seem to be bothered with this question.

Since Rashi is quoting [**Sifrei Devarim** § 252](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Devarim.252.3?vhe=Sifrei_Devarim,_Hebrew&lang=bi), I decided to look at the **HaEmek HaNetziv** *ad. loc.* Thankfully, I found that he addresses this.

> והא דנענשו עמונים ולא נזכרו בכל פרשת בלעם, אבל מכ"מ היו באותה מעשה שהחטיאו את ישראל כדאיתא בספרי פ' בלק באותה שעה עמדו עמונים ומואבים כו'. ובזה מיושב ק' תו' ב"ק ד ל"ח ב' ד"ה מואבים. וע' הגהות במ"ר פנחס פ' כ"א.‏

He says that even though Ammon isn't mentioned at all in the entire *parsha* of Bilaam and his plot to get the Jews to sin, the *Midrash* [**Sifrei Bamidbar 131**](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Bamidbar.131.2?vhe=Wikisource&lang=bi) mentions Ammon and Moav together in this plot ([Cf. Sanhedrin 106a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.106a.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), which uses similar wording as the Sifrei, but doesn't mention Ammon. Although, see below).

What's interesting is the Netziv there says that even though we don't see Ammon mentioned anywhere, since the Torah prohibits marrying into them, and the Sifrei that we started with mentions them together, we can assume they were involved. Sounds circular. The Netziv then says that this answers Tosafos' question in Bava Kamma 38b.

He then says to look at the "Hagahos Midrash Rabbah" to Bamidbar Rabbah § 21. I'm not sure what he's referring to, but my guess is [Bamidbar Rabbah 21:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Bamidbar_Rabbah.21.4?lang=bi), which says similar to the Sifrei we started with:

> רַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן אוֹמֵר מִנַּיִן שֶׁהַמַּחְטִיא אֶת הָאָדָם יוֹתֵר מִן הַהוֹרְגוֹ, שֶׁהַהוֹרֵג הוֹרֵג בָּעוֹלָם הַזֶּה, וְיֵשׁ לוֹ חֵלֶק לָעוֹלָם הַבָּא, וְהַמַּחְטִיא הוֹרְגוֹ בָּעוֹלָם הַזֶּה וּבָעוֹלָם הַבָּא. שְׁתֵּי אֻמּוֹת קִדְמוּ אֶת יִשְׂרָאֵל בְּחֶרֶב, וּשְׁתַּיִם בַּעֲבֵרָה, הַמִּצְרִים וַאֲדוֹמִים קִדְּמוּ בְּחֶרֶב...וּשְׁתַּיִם בַּעֲבֵרָה, מוֹאָבִים וְעַמּוֹנִים, עַל אֵלֶּה שֶׁקִּדְּמוּ בְּחֶרֶב, כְּתִיב (דברים כג, ח): לֹא תְתַעֵב אֲדֹמִי, לֹא תְתַעֵב מִצְרִי, אֲבָל אֵלּוּ שֶׁקִּדְּמוּ בַּעֲבֵרָה לְהַחְטִיא אֶת יִשְׂרָאֵל (דברים כג, ד): לֹא יָבֹא עַמּוֹנִי וּמוֹאָבִי, גַּם דּוֹר עֲשִׂירִי, עַד עוֹלָם.‏

On the words ושתים בעברה מואבים ועמונים, the [**Eitz Yosef**](https://www.sefaria.org/Bamidbar_Rabbah.21.4?lang=bi&p2=Etz_Yosef_on_Bamidbar_Rabbah.21.4.1&lang2=bi) cites the Sifrei in *parshas Pinchas* that the Netziv brought, and points out that [Sanhedrin 106a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.106a.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), which describes Bilam's plan, involved Ammonite wine. I suppose that implies their involvement.

The Netziv was probably referring to either the **Rashash** or the **Radal** *ad. loc.*, who wrote a lot on this topic.

Rashash:

> וכן איתא בספרי בלק עמדו עמונים ומואבים כו' והושיבו שם נשים כו' כדלעיל ס"פ בלק. ובזה מתורץ קושיית התוספות בב"ק ל"ח ב' ד"ה מואבים. וא"ת כו' ועמון מא"ל (וכן תמה הרמב"ן בפ' זו) וכו' ואעפ"י שמזכיר ב' פרדות על עמון לא איצטריך כו' אך לפי הספרי והמדרש א"ש בפשיטות.‏

He also cites the Sifrei in *parshas Balak*, and the *gemarra* in Sanhedrin. He also says that this answers Tosafos' question in Bava Kamma. Basically what the Netziv wrote.

Radal:

> ראיתי כתוב שהוא כמ"ש בספרי בלק שעמונים ומואבים יחד היו בעצת בלעם (ואפשר רמיזא בקרא (שופטים י) שאמר יפתח למלך בני עמון הטוב כו' מבלק בן צפור מלך מואב הרב רב את כו'. לומר שעמון היה אז ג"כ בעצה אחת עם בלק ובלעם) ובסנהדרין (קו.) אמרו וצרצור יין העמוני מונח כו'. ומפני שמואב ועמון נולדו ע"י זנות ויין לכן הכשילו לישראל ע"י שניהם. ומואב שהיתה פרוצה ביותר שהתחילה בעבירה ונראה בלשון מגונה לכן היו מעשיהם בעיקר העברה בזנות. ועמון רק ביין.

Besides citing the Sifrei in *parshas Balak*, he says that perhaps this idea is alluded to in [Shoftim 11:25](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.11.25?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). Yiftach sent a message to the King of Ammon, and says:

> וְעַתָּ֗ה הֲט֥וֹב טוֹב֙ אַתָּ֔ה מִבָּלָ֥ק בֶּן־צִפּ֖וֹר מֶ֣לֶךְ מוֹאָ֑ב הֲר֥וֹב רָב֙ עִם־יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל אִם־נִלְחֹ֥ם נִלְחַ֖ם בָּֽם׃
>
> “Besides, are you any better than Balak son of Zippor, king of Moab? Did he start a quarrel with Israel or go to war with them?

He then cites the *gemarra* in Sanhedrin. He finishes by saying that since the ancestors of the nations of Ammon and Moav were conceived through immoral relations and wine, therefore they chose to cause the Jews to stumble in these two things. Since Moav was the more immoral of the two, as evident by their name, they focused on the immoral relations. Ammon therefore focused on the wine.